# Generating unique filenames with tempnam

Tags: php

I looked at a few other questions mentioning `tempnam()` in the context of unique file naming.
I was left a bit unclear on whether the file names will be truly unique.

Let's say that we have a file upload script, that moves and renames the files to a permanent directory.

What I want to ask, is: Will the file name always be unique, when used like this:

```
$tmp_name = tempnam($dir, '');
unlink($tmp_name);
copy($uploaded_file, "$tmp_name.$ext");
```

Comment: I don't know, but you could try writing a script to generate a couple hundred names with tempnam in an array, and then checking to see if the same value comes up more than once. I'm not sure what happens if a file already exists with that name either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cantsay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881541/generating-unique-filenames-with-tempnam#comment36763725_23881600) suggested, I made a php script to look for identical values.

```
function tempnam_tst() {
    for ($i=0; $i < 250000 ; $i++) {

        $tmp_name = tempnam('/tmp/', '');
        unlink($tmp_name);
        $arr[$i] = $tmp_name;
    }

    return array_intersect($arr, array_unique(array_diff_key($arr, array_unique($arr))));
}

$arr = array();

do {
    $arr = tempnam_tst();
} while ( empty($arr) );

echo 'Matching items (case-sensitive):<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Matching items (case-sensitive):

Array
(
    [59996] => /tmp/8wB6RI
    [92722] => /tmp/KnFtJa
    [130990] => /tmp/KnFtJa
    [173696] => /tmp/8wB6RI
)
```

From what I can see, **`tempnam()` does not always generate an unique name**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
$uploadPath = "/upload/";
$fileName = time().$_FILES['file_name']['name'];
$tempName = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempName,$uploadPath.$fileName);
```

This will upload unique file in upload folder.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I am asking about. To clarify, I know how to make unique filenames, but out of interest, want to know if `tempnam()` will provide the same functionality.

Comment: I think that should be `$_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']` without the E in temp

Comment: This one will provide unique file name  `time().$_FILES['file_name']['name'];`

Comment: tbh, it is $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] edit: actually, isn't the $1 in $_FILES[$1] dependant on the form field name

Comment: Never use $_FILES['file_name']['name'] as a name on your system without filtering. This data is from the user and could be dirty.